# return multiple json encoded array from the server

Tags: ajax, json

I want to know how can I return multiple encoded JSON array from the server

ex.

//client

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'items-details.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {member_id: 1},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(responseText) {

    }
});
```

//server, items-details.php

```
//some code here
```

then, the final output is ex. itemsData array and itemsCategories array, then I use json_encode() on both array. but how can I return both arrays to the client? I only know how to handle echo() - which is treated by the client as string

before, I only use

```
echo(json_encode(itemsData));
```

then the client will parse it .. but how can I return multiple json encoded array: itemsData and itemsCategories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you could create let's say a `$response` array, which could contain both the `$itemsData` and `$itemsCategories` arrays.

```
// $itemsData and $itemsCategories defined here

$response = array(
    $itemsData, $itemsCategories
);

return json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a json object that holds both or your arrays and json_encode that object and render that: json_encode(items = { data: itemsData, categories: itemsCategories })

Answer (score 0):

@edgeofmystery, you get right answer but if you return assoc
 array it will be easier / more comfortable to parse it

```
$response = array(
    "itemsData"=>$itemsData, "itemsCategories"=>$itemsCategories
);

echo json_encode($response);
```